# Selective data reading from python using pdfminer or any other library

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tesseract, pdfminer

one of the pages of a pdf file which consists of 727 pages from which I have to read the data:

[image: one of the pages of a pdf file which consists of 727 pages from which I have to read the data]

I want to read the data marked within the red rectangle using pdfminer in python

is there any specific parameter or function

or should I use another library? if yes then can you please mention it with the required function

please keep in mind that there are multiple pages like this in the actual file which I have to read and cropping them individually is not an option and the process needs to be automated.

Comment: What code have you tried? How did the results differ from what you want/expect?

Comment: @ebbishop
I've tried pdfminer but it converts the entire page into the text file
I only want the texts for data which are smaller in size
like the one marked in this image